# How to access properties in parent pom from child pom

Tags: maven

I tried to pass properties from child pom to parent pom  and parent pom is not getting the the child pom property value. Is there a way to pass properties from child pom to parent pom ?

Comment: Could you please provide the example pom?

Comment: (parent pom)
<properties> 
<person>${name}</person> 
<properties> 

(child pom)
<properties> 
<name>Bill</name> 
<properties>

Comment: The parent cannot see the child property.

Comment: What is your exact needs , which plugin needs a property through child to parent ?

Comment: Need - I want to pass values from child pom to parent pom

Comment: @spider: As Charlee pointed out, the parent pom will not be able to "see" properties from the child pom. It only works the other way around. What does work, is using a variable in a plugin definition in the parent pom and the set different values in two child poms. Hope that helps